# Unable to fetch test company details in linkedin

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I tried to use the below api with the test company ID, but getting "

> Unknown authentication scheme

".

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/relation-to-viewer/is-company-share-enabled?format=json

*#2414183 is the test company ID provided by linkedIn*

LinkedIn docs says there is no authentication needed for working on test company. 
Any one please help me where im wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every** LinkedIn API call requires authentication.  It's not always the case that a developer is listed as an administrator of a company, which is required to make certain API calls.  The test company simply acts as a testing entity that every developer is considered an administrator of, to facilitate testing, but that does not mean that you do not have to be authenticated to try make the call.